# Callback calls parent function eventually crashes app

Tags: javascript

I have some Javascript which is executed every day on sunset. Since the time of sunset varies every day, I set a new timer for tomorrow once the current sunset timer is executed.

```
scheduleSunTimer(timer) {

    let _timer = timer;

    let time = getSunset(new Date(), config.latitude, config.longitude);

    schedule.scheduleJob(time, () => {
        this.console.log('Timer actived');

        // Reschedule for next day
        this.scheduleSunTimer(_timer);
    });

}
```

I use the `node-schedule` library from https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule/

This code works for a while, but after a week my application hangs. It looks like the callback of `schedule.scheduleJob` calling `scheduleSunTimer` again creates some never ending nested call stack. This might cause a memory leak which causes my app to crash.

I was wondering if anyone know how to avoid the call stack from growing, or might know a better solution / best practise for this.

Comment: I suspect that you have an indirect infinite recursion and the first call to this function never terminates. I suggest you add a `console.log()` at the very end of this function to see if it is executed.

Comment: Assuming scheduleJob should be async, there shouldn't be a continuously growing callstack of one calling the other. Is a job that is scheduled done only once or is it executed at an interval

Comment: Please post the code of `schedule.scheduleJob`

Comment: @PatricEvans the job is only executed once without interval.

Comment: @Bergi: the schedule.scheduleJob code could be found at https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule/blob/master/lib/schedule.js#L593

Comment: @PatrickEvans I understand, but pasting the relevant code makes me paste the whole lib. I prefer to add the pieces of code later when I know what caused the problem. Otherwise my question is cluttered with the complete library code.

Comment: Would it be too much to ask to use `rescheduleJob()` - I mean that is exactly your use case and would allow you to reuse the scheduled job rather than creating them over and over and over. Alternatively, you might actually consider cancelling the existing job prior to starting a new one. Seems like standard event listener discipline to me. If you put it up, you should clean it up too...right?

Comment: @RandyCasburn that would probably the best way to handle this. I have to see how it would fit in. Still wondering what would be the best practise for these kind of nested calls though

Comment: IMHO, the best practice hasn't really ever changed. It is what I referred to as _Event Listener Discipline_, if you are writing code that creates event call backs, you have the responsibility of ensuring those event listeners get cleaned up when they are no longer required.  Pretty straight forward.